# Fetching users data based on username input in urls

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am little bit new to django and was working on my first instagram clone project all by myself. I got confused in a place where I needed to fetch user data based on 127.0.0.1:8000/username and I found a useful but useless answer(for me) from [medium(.com)](https://medium.com/@selfengineeredd/how-to-get-users-based-on-usernames-in-django-723524ec68d4) .The author was using class based view. In class based view, I didnot get any documentation to use multiple models as much as I searched so i had to do it with function based view as I have not learned class based view yet.I had to use post model, profile model and User model to get data for profile page.

This is the code that somehow worked but should I use this view?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

#profile view
def profile_data(request, username):   
    mydata = User.objects.get(username=username)
    myprofile = Profile.objects.filter(user=mydata)
    mycontext ={'profile': myprofile}
    return render(request,'firstapp/profile.html', context=mycontext)
```

```
#in urls.py,
from firstapp import views
path('<str:username>/', views.profile_data , name='profile'),

#in models.py,
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,unique=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.fullname
```

```
In firstapp/profile.html,

<a href="#" class="text-3xl mt-5 text-center">{{user.profile.fullname}}
```

But I got confused on how to attatch my Profile model in it. So I created this, my own function-based view for it after few hours of researching . Is this ok to use or will give any error in my back? Thank you

I am expecting to get new ways or the correction or additon in my code if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems ok, but be careful about the url part, because you will have problems when adding new urls (eg: /login) because it might be treated as a username.

You could get away by editing the order in your urlpatterns so the profile page is the last but now you have an issue if a user has the same username as a url in your page.

For example if a user has "login" as username, you won't be able to go to their profile page.

A solution is to use a prefix for the profile pages (eg: `/u/<username>` or `/@<username>`).

Some other improvements:

```py
    mydata = User.objects.get(username=username)
    myprofile = Profile.objects.filter(user=mydata)
```

Can be rewriten with only one request:

```py
    user = User.objects.get(username=username).select_related("profile")
    myprofile = user.profile
```

See the documentation for select_related: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

You should also handle the case where the user is not found:

```py
    try:
        user = User.objects.select_related("profile").get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("No User matches the given query.")

    myprofile = user.profile
```

Comment: Hello @luxcem, thanks for answer but I wanna ask if there is any way of disallowing users choose some reserved terms like 'login', 'register', 'admin' ,for their usernames in django?

Comment: You'll have to do the validation manually, either in the forms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/ or in the model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/validators/